# How to match <sup>value</sup> in XSL-FO

Tags: xpath, xsl-fo

I'm using xsl-fo and trying to style xref content within a `<sup>`

eg I want to make the 2 superscript.

`<sup id="FNB-0002"><xref href="#Comp_CLJONLINE_CLJ_2010_04_2/FN-0002">2</xref></sup>`

I am using the following code which I think should work.

```
 <xsl:template match="sup[@id='*']">    
        <fo:inline font-size="24pt" font-weight="bold" text-indent="2em" text-transform="uppercase" >
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
            </fo:inline>
    </xsl:template>
```

But none of the styles I am applying are being recognised. I'm beginning to think that this is because the 2 is within an xref and the xsl-fo is then ignoring it.

Could anyone give me some pointers as how to cater for and style these sups

Thanks,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this template is not matching your `<sup>` element is because you are matching a `<sup>` with an `id` attribute that has the value `*`.

If you are trying to match `<sup>` elements that have an `id` attribute, change your match to this:

```
sup[@id]
```

Also, try using `vertical-align="super"` for superscript text.

Example:

```
<fo:inline vertical-align="super" font-size="8pt">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
</fo:inline>
```