# XSL-FO - use <fo:character /> to replace a character's formatting everywhere in <xsl:template match="/">

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

I'd like to make ® (not ™) always appear as superscript in my xsl-fo output. I cannot wrap it in <sup> tags as it will mess with our translation / localization process. Can this be done with <fo:character /> ?

Answer (score 0):

Please take the time to carefully research your problem. `<sup>` tags are used in HTML, not XSL-FO.

Instead, you achieve superscript as follows:

```
<fo:inline vertical-align="super">
The said character.
</fo:inline>
```

Using the `fo:inline` attribute `baseline-shift` would work as well.
This might be related to your question: [How to match <sup>value</sup> in XSL-FO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718411/how-to-match-supvalue-sup-in-xsl-fo)

**EDIT**: Where input XML is concerned, it is best practice (i.e. most convenient) to have an indication for extra formatting in the code itself. Either you can break your paragraph into several "runs" if the formatting changes (e.g. Office OpenXML, this is approx. what it looks like):

```
<paragraph>
 <run>This is normal text</run>
 <run>This is superscript</run>
 <run>Normal text again</run>
</paragraph>
```

Or embed the superscript element into the text content like this:

```
<paragraph>
 <text>This is normal text <font align="super">superscript text</font>normal text</text>
</paragraph>
```

Now, try to transform your XML to fit one or the other representation. For example, have a look at `xsl:character-map`. It might be possible to map the ® character to `<font align="super">®</font>` in the output tree.

Comment: Thanks Mathias, I apologize for not being specific enough. I can't target the character directly in a string as the XSL doing the transformation is being fed an XML doc that looks something like this:    <root><product>Wicked Cool Gizmo®</product></root> --- and in the interest of translation, we can't add any markup, be it HTML or xsl-fo in our authoring forms.  Any other suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you, sir!

Comment: Use indendation or backticks - otherwise your code does not show up in the comment ;-)

Comment: So, you mean that you cannot isolate ® into the text content of a separate element? i.e. it always co-occurs with other characters?

Comment: Yes, that is true. I'm considering editing the glyph itself in the font. And being as we are loading a font specifically for xsl-fo/PDF generation and the stakeholders want a consistent registered trademark display, this seems like the way to go.

Comment: Well unless you are a professional at building fonts and understand all the concepts that go into a font and the bounding information, I would say it's not the "way to go". your choice. Modifying the behavior of a character in the font because you wish it displaced can in some instances modify the way the font is treated with the text in a line, in a paragraph (like understanding that a displaced character can affect line spacing).

Comment: I agree with @Kevin Brown. Edited my answer.

Comment: Many thanks Kevin and Mathias for your time and advice. It is greatly appreciated although we did go ahead with modifying the glyph with TT3. Preliminary dynamic PDF generation results are lookin' good :-)

Comment: Please consider marking this as an answer (the tick to the left) if it was helpful to you. Cheers!

Comment: Mathias - I all appreciate the time you took and your continued correspondence, and I apologize for not being specific enough in posting my questions, but we have a strict requirement of not having any markup in our content string, so: `code`<font align="super">some text</font> would not be an appropriate solution as this markup would appear in the XML feed and interfere with our translation process. If, perhaps there was a way to target the registered trademark symbol to be superscripted OUTSIDE the text string itself that would be great, but simply changing the glyph seems to be working fine